# jQuery if / else

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Here's my situation :
First when load the page I set `a` to `1`.
Then I want to click in a button that have an if that set `a` to `0` , so when I click in him again the if condition shouldn't happen.

Here's my code :

```
$('#menu2b').click(function(){
    $('#menu1a').fadeIn(0);$('#menu1b').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu2a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu2b').fadeIn(0);
    $('#menu3a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu3b').fadeIn(0);
    $('#menu4a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu4b').fadeIn(0);
    $('#menu5a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu5b').fadeIn(0);
    $('#menu6a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu6b').fadeIn(0);

    if (a = 1){
        $('.main').delay(50).animate({marginTop : "-=160px"},{duration: 1000});
        $('.footer').delay(220).animate({marginTop : "-=150px"},{duration: 1000});
        $('.container2').animate({marginTop : "-=90px"},{duration: 0}).delay(200).fadeIn(0).slideUp(0).slideDown(1500);
        var a = 0;
    }
    else {}
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container2').fadeOut(0);
    $('.container3').fadeOut(0);
    $('.container4').fadeOut(0);
    $('.container5').fadeOut(0);
    $('.container6').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu1b').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu2a').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu3a').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu4a').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu5a').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu6a').fadeOut(0);
    var a = 1;
});
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (a = 1){
```

is assigning the value `1` to `a`, unconditionally, and always evaluate as true. You probably want

```
if (a == 1){
```

which is TESTING to see if `a` equals `1`.

Comment: Or even better, `a === 1`

Comment: Now I changed "=" to "==" and the button isn't working.. any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but try this:

```
var a = true;

$('#menu2b').click(function(){
    $('#menu1a').fadeIn(0);$('#menu1b').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu2a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu2b').fadeIn(0);
    $('#menu3a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu3b').fadeIn(0);
    $('#menu4a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu4b').fadeIn(0);
    $('#menu5a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu5b').fadeIn(0);
    $('#menu6a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu6b').fadeIn(0);
    if(a == true){
        $('.main').delay(50).animate({marginTop : "-=160px"},{duration: 1000});
        $('.footer').delay(220).animate({marginTop : "-=150px"},{duration: 1000});
        $('.container2').animate({marginTop : "-=90px"},{duration: 0}).delay(200).fadeIn(0).slideUp(0).slideDown(1500);
        a = false;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container2').fadeOut(0);
    $('.container3').fadeOut(0);
    $('.container4').fadeOut(0);
    $('.container5').fadeOut(0);
    $('.container6').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu1b').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu2a').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu3a').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu4a').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu5a').fadeOut(0);
    $('#menu6a').fadeOut(0);
});
```

I've changed your `=` in the if statement to `==`, which is the correct comparison operator.  `===` would also work, as would `if(a)`. Variable `a` also needs to be global (moved to to the top of the script, outside any functions) so the click function can access it. I also changed it to a boolean, which is a more appropriate data type.

Also, your `else{}` didn't do anything, so I removed it.

Comment: button still not working :(

Comment: Could you post a link to your full code so we can see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable a as global. Instead of local variable

```
  var a = 1;

  $('#menu2b').click(function(){
  $('#menu1a').fadeIn(0);$('#menu1b').fadeOut(0);
  $('#menu2a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu2b').fadeIn(0);
  $('#menu3a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu3b').fadeIn(0);
  $('#menu4a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu4b').fadeIn(0);
  $('#menu5a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu5b').fadeIn(0);
  $('#menu6a').fadeOut(0);$('#menu6b').fadeIn(0);
  if(a == 1)
  {
    $('.main').delay(50).animate({marginTop : "-=160px"},{duration: 1000});
    $('.footer').delay(220).animate({marginTop : "-=150px"},{duration: 1000});
    $('.container2').animate({marginTop : "-=90px"},{duration: 0}).delay(200).fadeIn(0).slideUp(0).slideDown(1500);
    a = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
    }

});

 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.container2').fadeOut(0);
$('.container3').fadeOut(0);
$('.container4').fadeOut(0);
$('.container5').fadeOut(0);
$('.container6').fadeOut(0);
$('#menu1b').fadeOut(0);
$('#menu2a').fadeOut(0);
$('#menu3a').fadeOut(0);
$('#menu4a').fadeOut(0);
$('#menu5a').fadeOut(0);
$('#menu6a').fadeOut(0);
           });
```

Comment: do not work :/ the button is not working when introduce "==" idk why.